# Magento and Mailchimp webhook 404

Tags: configuration, newsletter, 404

I'am administrating a site in Magento 1.9.0.1 with mailchimp integration. We had a newsletter subscription problem (users didn't get subscribed in magento) and I noticed that the webhook configured in mailchimp gives 404.

How do I proper configure a magento webhook for mailchimp ?

I really appreciate any help you can provide, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by myself.

If you are having a 404 with mailchimp webhook, just go to magento admin

> System \ Configuration \ Mailchimp

and hit the "Save config" button. Even if you don't change anything it will automatically regenerate the webhook in your mailchimp account.

Hope this solution can help somebody else.